# Accessing contents of a string using variables

Tags: c++, string, variables, printing

I am currently working on something that requires me to access individuals parts of a string. I seem to have a strange bug occurring with string syntax.

Here is my problem:

say you have a string

```
string str = "hello";
```

You can access individual characters in that string using `str[0]`, `str[1]`.
Example:

```
cout << str[0];
```

prints: `'h'`

However, using the following syntax, nothing will be printed.

```
int i = 0;

cout << str[i];
```

No matter what type of variable I use I get the same result. Can anyone help?

Comment: Post the whole code.

Comment: This should work given your provided example. See this -- http://ideone.com/DTzXz

Comment: Could be the buffer for cout isn't getting flushed. Try putting "cout << str[i] << endl;". Other than that, we'll need to see more code.

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org).

Comment: -1 inconsistent. as i'm writing this comment the information given is inconsistent. which probably means that it's very incomplete, and that the problem is about something the OP failed to mention.

Answer (score -2):

String is a C++ object, it's not stored as character array like in C, so you can't access its invidual part. It should be convert to C character array to access its part.
Try this:

```
cout <<str.c_str()[i];
```

Comment: Um. Huh ? str[i] fires one of a variety of operator[](size_t i) across the str object returning either a char& or a const char&. Not only is this wrong, its wrong in multiple assumptions.